# Identifier expected error(not usual answer)

Tags: java

so I looked at the many other identifier expected answers and they didn't seem to fit. I have the entire code in my main class, but not in my main method. I feel like I'm just missing something simple.

```js
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class L7C14 
{
    public void QuickSort(int[], int min, int max)//this is where Im getting the ID error. I placed it at the top for Q/A purposes. quick sort is just supposed to be another method in my class L7C14. 
        {
            int middle = min + ( (max-min) /2);//not finished with code logic in here
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] nums = new int[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please make a selection: Would you like to input 10 numbers (1) or randomly generate them (2)");
        
        if(input.nextInt()==1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Number "+(i+1)+"?");
                nums[i] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
               {
                   nums[i] = rand.nextInt(648);
               }
        }
        //now the array is fully populated
        //display numbers[]
        System.out.println("Your numbers are");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
        /* I think this looks better
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\n"+nums[i]);
        }
        */
        
    } 

        //now sort lowest to highest, display
        //sort highest to lowest, display
   
}
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? And, why are you tagging this as JavaScript when it is clearly Java?

Comment: Didn't even realize. This whole question was poorly formatted.. just gonna take it down, since I figured it out. Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

Just realized I didn't identify the parameters properly, not listing the [] name. Looking for question deletion option.